# Why does session window example not adhere to the max 10 minute timeout?

Tags: azure

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-streaming#session-window

Assume max duration is 10 minute, and timeout is 5 min.

Why does the 2nd window not adhere to the 10 min max duration? I think that the example is wrong and would be correct if the max duration was configured as 60 minutes and not 10 minutes?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first it looks confusing but what the picture shows is accurate. If you read carefully the microsoft documentation-For example, if the max duration is 10, then the checks on if the window exceed maximum duration will happen at t = 0, 10, 20, 30, etc.

So let us take the second window-

> A check happened before the second window started at exactly 10 seconds for any max window violation. No violations since no window is active.
> At about 13 seconds the event 3 occurs and starts the window 2(important to remember window 2 started at 13 sec) . At 15 seconds event 4. Since they are within the 5 second timeout bracket, the window 2 continues.
> At 20 seconds 2 things happen. One is event 5 which is within 5 second of event 4 (15 s) and hence is still in window 2. Second there is a max window violation check(20). Since window 2 started at 13 sec it is only 7 sec old. Hence it has not violated the 10 sec max duration. So it allows window 2 to continue.
> Window 2 continues to receive events before 5 sec time out till it reaches 30 sec. Now the 30 sec Max duration check kicks in. It notices window 2 has been running for 17 sec(started at 13) and hence now window 2 will be stopped.

Hope this helps.